Why are my Alt codes in Windows 11 showing the wrong character?
I tried to do Alt+255 in Windows 11 laptop to make an invisible character for my file name, but it results in ÿ. Why is it doing this? How?
All my other stuff are fine, like Alt+0146 for ’ instead of '(apostrophe), 0145 for ‘(backwards tilted apostrophe), 0147 for “(the first quote mark in quotes), and 0148 for ”(second quote mark)

Did you use 255 or 0255?

See https://altcodeunicode.com/

Alt codes without leading zeroes (Alt nnn) produce characters & symbols based on IBM Code Page 437 / DOS.
Alt codes with leading zeroes (Alt 0nnn) produce characters & symbols based on Windows Code Page 1252.




Char
Alt Code
Char Name
Unicode
Char
Alt Code
Char Name
Unicode




 
Alt 255
No-break space, non-breaking space, nbsp
U+00A0
ÿ
Alt 0255
Latin small letter y with diaeresis
U+00FF



